Having issue migrating Milvus data from ver 2.x to another machine
I am looking for an option to export milvus data in ver 2.4 (sort of backup), and then migrate it to another machine. According to the doc, there is such option for migrating from ver 1,x.
Is it possible to perform milvus-migration export from ver 2.4?
When I tried it I got error message indicating that the migration tool is attempting to use metadata database connection arguments. It seems the tool requires a specific mode to handle Milvus 2.x without MySQL..
(venv) qa@Ubuntu2204-2f3833:~/MILVUS-MIGRATION/work$ ./milvus-migration export --config=./configs/export_m2m.yaml
[2024/07/24 13:57:06.174 +03:00] [ERROR] [cmd/export.go:46] ["fail to export meta collection, empty meta db connect args"] [stack="github.com/zilliztech/milvus-migration/cmd.init.func1\n\t/home/qa/MILVUS-MIGRATION/milvus-migration/cmd/export.go:46\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\t/home/qa/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:987\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\t/home/qa/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\t/home/qa/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039\ngithub.com/zilliztech/milvus-migration/cmd.Execute\n\t/home/qa/MILVUS-MIGRATION/milvus-migration/cmd/root.go:26\nmain.main\n\t/home/qa/MILVUS-MIGRATION/milvus-migration/main.go:16\nruntime.main\n\t/snap/go/10660/src/runtime/proc.go:271"]

(venv) qa@Ubuntu2204-2f3833:~/MILVUS-MIGRATION/work$ cat ./configs/export_m2m.yaml
dumper:
worker:
limit: 2
workMode: milvus1x
reader:
bufferSize: 1024
writer:
bufferSize: 1024

loader:
worker:
limit: 16

meta:
mode: none

source:
mode: local
local:
tablesDir: /home/qa/MILVUS/milvus/tables/

target:
mode: local
local:
outputDir: /home/qa/MILVUS/milvus/migration/output/
milvus2x:
endpoint: "localhost:19530"
username: xxxx
password: xxxx


I have worked with Milvus migration before and found this documentation quite helpful: https://github.com/zilliztech/milvus-migration/blob/main/README_2X.md. But note that it only supports migration between Milvus 2.x versions.
If you also wish to import your dataset, you can first try converting your dataset to json file or numpy file, and then use bulkInsert function to import to Milvus. Milvus function bulkInsert() supports json file or numpy file:
https://docs.zilliz.com/docs/import-data-via-sdks
